# Getting the scroll bar to ignore a fixed div at the top of the page

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

On this site here:

http://acp.studevent.co.uk/

I have a fixed div at the top which will act as a menu and a content div below containing everything else. I cannot figure out how to use overflow-y: scroll so that the pages scroll bar is only used for the content div and ignores the header div at the top.

Comment: The original page scroll bar will not scroll the `fixed` div, but if you want the `content` to have its own scrollbar then give it the `overflow-y:scroll;` and some `height`.

Comment: I can't really give the content div a fixed height as its determined by the div's inside of it meaning the scroll bar for the content div is disabled, any thoughts?

Comment: Use `overflow:auto;` with `max-height`, this way, if the content are not so big, you wont see a scroll bar, but when the content is big, a scroll bar will be created.

Comment: Still have the problem of having to specify a height, basically need to content div's height to be dynamic depending on how big the window is. Using a max-height still means there's a set height somewhere in there.

Comment: Well if you want your content to be dynamic, if you want it to expand, then why the scroll bar?

Comment: Because I want to be able to scroll up and down the content div using the menu bar as navigation but the menu bar at the top not to be part of the scrolling area.

Comment: This is the last thing I could do http://jsfiddle.net/AliBassam/YMfRV/

Answer (score 0):

PrimeFaces's layout/layoutUnit components do exactly what you needed. And if I'm not mistaken, they use javascript to calculate and set an height to the content. Each time you resize your page it recalculates the values.

You can check their showcase:
http://primefaces.org/showcase/ui/layoutFull.jsf

I dare say, you need to set a fixed height for overflow-y'to work. And one way to make it dynamic is to somehow calculate the necessary values.

Also you could make them have dynamically calculated fixed heights by using css positioning and left-right-top-bottom properties.

Best regards..